# Many to many relationship on Mongodb based e-learning webapp?

Tags: mongodb

I am relatively new to No-SQL databases. I am designing a data structure for an e-learning web app. There would be X quantity of courses and Y quantity of users.

Every user will be able to take any number of courses.

Every course will be compound of many sections (each section may be a video or a quiz).

I will need to keep track of every section a user takes, so I think the whole course should be part of the user set (for each user), like so:

```
{
   _id: "ed",
   name: "Eduardo Ibarra",
   courses: [
                {
                  name: "Node JS",
                  progress: "100%",
                  section: [
                      {name: "Introdiction", passed:"100%", field3:"x", field4:""},
                      {name: "Quiz 1", passed:"75%", questions:[...], field3:"x", field4:""},
                  ]
                },
                {
                  name: "MongoDB",
                  progress: "65%",
                  ...
                }
              ]
 }
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: I am really wondering why did you decide to do in in Mongo? You seem to be busy solving problems that are trivial and natural for any RDMS. Why not to keep just schema-less data in Mongo (if that is the reason you picked it).

Comment: @Andrey, I thought it would simplify the structure of the courses, since the section numbers, type of sections, number of quizes and number of answers (and right answers) per quiz will vary a lot.

Comment: @Mulritut you need to understand that you trade simplicity of structure for easiness of retrieval (joins), relationships and integrity. Everything can be modeled in RDBMS, if your sole argument for using NoSql was to cut corners than I have some bad news for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that design your database depending upon your queries. One thing is for sure.. You will have to do some embedding.

If you are going to perform more queries on what a user is doing, then make user as the primary entity and embed the courses within it. You don't need to embed the entire course info. The info about a course is static. For ex: the data about Node JS course - i.e. the content, author of the course, exercise files etc - will not change. So you can keep the courses' info separately in another collection. But how much of the course a user has completed is dependent on the individual user. So you should only keep the id of the course (which is stored in the separate 'course' collection) and for each user you can store the information that is related to that (User, Course) pair embedded in the user collection itself.

Now the most important question - what to do if you have to perform queries which require 'join' of user and course collections? For this you can use javascript to first get the courses (and maybe store them in an array or list etc) and then fetch the user for each of those courses from the courses collection or vice-versa. There are a few drivers available online to help you accomplish this. One is UnityJDBC which is available [here](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php).

From my experience, I understand that knowing what you are going to query from MongoDB is very helpful in designing your database because the NoSQL nature of MongoDB implies that you have no correct way for designing. Every way is incorrect if it does not allow you in accomplishing your task. So clearly, knowing beforehand what you will do (i.e. what you will query) with the database is the only guide.